# flutter chat app with stream.io Adding extraData into user properties

Tags: flutter, getstream-io

i am looking to add extraData into the user properties but i am having this error: The argument type 'List<Map<String, String>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'User'. i am currently using stream.io sdk for my flutter chat application. any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
Future<void> joinChannel(BuildContext context, int index) async {
    final core = StreamChatCore.of(context);
    final client = StreamChatCore.of(context).client;
    final channel = core.client.channel('messaging',
        id: _areaOfInterest[index].replaceAll(' ', ''),
        extraData: {
          'name': _areaOfInterest[index],
        });

    await channel.watch();

    await channel.addMembers([core.currentUser!.id]);

    await client.updateUser([
      {_areaOfInterest[index]: 'member'}
    ]);

    Navigator.of(context).push(
      CommunityChatScreen.routeWithChannel(channel),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `updateUser` method expects a `User` object. You're trying to pass in a List.

Here is an example of an approach you can take:

```dart
final client = StreamChatCore.of(context).client;

// Get the current user or create a user object and give needed info, `User();`
final currentUser = client.state.currentUser!;

// Get the extra data for the user and update with new info
final extraData = currentUser.extraData;
extraData['storeSomethingElse'] = 'something else';

// Update user
final updatedUser = currentUser.copyWith(
  extraData: extraData,
);
await client.updateUser(updatedUser);
```